# Comparing cardinalities between infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

What is the relation of the cardinalities of the following two sets A and B, where A = the set of all subsets of the set of all even natural numbers and B = the set of all ﬁnite subsets of the set of all rational numbers?

My reasoning:

B is countable because the set of finite subset of a countably infinite set is countable. Therefore, we have that B as the same cardinality of the set of natural numbers. Furthermore, the set of all even natural numbers has the same cardinality of the set of natural numbers, as I guess we can find a bijection among them. But by Cantor's theorem as |P(X)|>|X|, therefore A as a greater cardinality of the set of natural numbers, hence, |A|>|B|.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, what should I change? On top of that, do you have any tips on how to write it formally, in a proper proof?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. How to write it up nicely depends on what results you already have available to use. It might be enough to write something like this:

> Let $E$ be the set of all even natural numbers. Then $$|A|=|\wp(E)|>|E|=|\Bbb N|=|B|\,,$$ where the inequality is from Cantor’s theorem, and the last two equalities are known results.